# Unknown Error in Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

I have this code in my Yii Music Store Application, but I didn't know the error(s). My idea is to show/browse the category/criteria of album, artist, and genre. But it always show "the else condition". I have tried to fix it but I can't find the error(s). The code is below. Hope anyone can fix it. Thanks all

```
<?php

class StoreController extends Controller
{
public $message;

public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->message = "Hello from Store.Index()";
    $this->render('index', array('content'=>$this->message));
}

public function actionBrowse()
{
    if(isset($_GET["gid"])){
        $gid = $_GET["gid"];

        $genreCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $genreCriteria->select = "`GenreId`, `Name`, `Description`";
        $genreCriteria->condition = "genreId = " . $_GET["gid"];

        $artistCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $artistCriteria->alias = "t1";
        $artistCriteria->select = "DISTINCT `t1`.`Name`, `t1`.`ArtistId`";
        $artistCriteria->join = "LEFT JOIN `tbl_album` ON `tbl_album`.`ArtistId` = `t1` . `ArtistId`";
        $artistCriteria->order = "`t1`.`ArtistId` ASC";

        $albumCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $albumCriteria->alias = "t2";
        $albumCriteria->select = "`AlbumId`, `GenreId`, `Title`, `Price`, `AlbumArtUrl`";
        $albumCriteria->condition = "`GenreId` = " . $_GET["gid"];
        $albumCriteria->order = "`ArtistId` ASC";

        $this->render('index', array('Albums' => Album::model()->findAll($albumCriteria),
                                     'Artist' => Artist::model()->findAll($artistCriteria),
                                     'Genre' => Genre::model()->findAll($artistCriteria)));
    }else{
        $this->message = "Hello from Store.Browse()";
        $this->render('index', array('content'=>$this->message));
    }
}

public function actionDetails()
{
    $this->message = "Hello from Store.Details()";
    $this->render('index', array('content'=>$this->message));
}

// Uncomment the following methods and override them if needed
/*
public function filters()
{
    // return the filter configuration for this controller, e.g.:
    return array(
        'inlineFilterName',
        array(
            'class'=>'path.to.FilterClass',
            'propertyName'=>'propertyValue',
        ),
    );
}

public function actions()
{
    // return external action classes, e.g.:
    return array(
        'action1'=>'path.to.ActionClass',
        'action2'=>array(
            'class'=>'path.to.AnotherActionClass',
            'propertyName'=>'propertyValue',
        ),
    );
}
*/
}
```

Comment: what is your url for this?

Comment: so, is, $_GET actually populated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer is pretty simple, your page URL is missing "gid" and its value. This is the only reasonable explanation for "if isset" condition to fall under "else" section.

You can make a quick confirmation test. Go to your browser, enter **www.yoursitename.com/store/browse?gid=111** and then see if it'll get the results you need. Keep in mind that i don't know your exact URL and its structure, so it's just an example, but the part "/**browse?gid=111**" is pretty important. It simple creates "gid" for $_POST array and sets its value equal to "111".

Additional note: together with "isset" you can also check up if "gid" value is empty or not, sometimes it's helpful and safer this way.

*Also, here's my version of your Yii code:*

```
$genreCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $genreCriteria->select = "GenreId, Name, Description";
    $genreCriteria->condition = "genreId = " . $_GET["gid"];

    $artistCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $artistCriteria->alias = "t1";
    $artistCriteria->select = "DISTINCT t1.Name, t1.ArtistId";
    $artistCriteria->join = "LEFT JOIN tbl_album ON tbl_album.ArtistId = t1.ArtistId";
    $artistCriteria->order = "t1.ArtistId ASC";

    $albumCriteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $albumCriteria->alias = "t2";
    $albumCriteria->select = "AlbumId, GenreI, Title, Price, AlbumArtUrl";
    $albumCriteria->condition = "GenreId = " . $_GET["gid"];
    $albumCriteria->order = "ArtistId ASC";
```

As you see, i simply removed quotes. This code wasn't tested locally in Yii, but the query itself - worked fine for me.

Comment: I have tried, my url is http://localhost/musicstore/index.php?r=store/browse&id=7. I changed as you said to http://localhost/musicstore/index.php?r=store/browse?gid=7 and nothing happens but Error 404 - The system is unable to find the requested action "browse?gid=7".

Sorry I really a newbie in Yii and PHP

Comment: Hey, almost there, try with http://localhost/musicstore/index.php?r=store/browse&gid=7.

Your URL has "id" instead of "gid"

Comment: okay thanks, now the problem is:
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.'Name', 't1'.'ArtistId' FROM `tbl_artist` `t1` LEFT JOIN 'tbl_artist' ON 'tbl_a' at line 1. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT DISTINCT 't1'.'Name', 't1'.'ArtistId' FROM `tbl_artist` `t1` LEFT JOIN 'tbl_artist' ON 'tbl_album'.'ArtistId' ORDER BY 't1'.'ArtistId' ASC

Am I wrong with the code above?

Comment: This question is actually out of the current topic's scope, but here's the solution.

You have issue with quotes/inverted commas.
My variant of your MySQL query is "SELECT DISTINCT t1.Name, t1.ArtistId FROM tbl_artist t1 LEFT JOIN tbl_album ON tbl_album.ArtistId ORDER BY t1.ArtistId ASC". I simply removed all your quotes.

I edited my original answer with my version of your CDbCommand part to keep this comment short.